# Write the value of a JTextField to a variable of type String from another class (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, variables, jtextfield

I am very difficult to record the value typed into a JTextField that belongs to class 1 in variable of type String that belongs to class 2, for example, if I type the word "Test" in the JTextField class 1 when i press the button in class 1, I would like the value entered in the JTextField class 1 is recorded on a variable type String in class 2, so I use this variable as I want, can you give me a hand with that? I've tried to create an object of class 1 and use the getText and to String, but no success yet. When i see the System in the class2 the result is NULL ! :(

Thank you.

The code :

```
public class Class1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Class1() {    
        initComponents();    
    }    
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          

    private void initComponents() {
        fieldOfClass1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();    
        bottonOfClass1 = new javax.swing.JButton();    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());    
        getContentPane().add(fieldOfClass1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 39, 336, 38));    
        bottonOfClass1.setText("Botton");    
        bottonOfClass1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
                bottonActionPerformed(evt);    
            }    
        });

        getContentPane().add(bottonOfClass1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 114, 161, 45));
        pack();

    }// </editor-fold>  
    private void bottonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

Class2 classTwo = new Class2();

    classTwo.receiveFieldValueOfClass1= returnField();
        System.out.println(classTwo.receiveFieldValueOfClass1);
    } 

    String returnField(){    
      return fieldOfClass1.getText().toString();
    }    

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         new Class1().setVisible(true);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify  
    private javax.swing.JButton bottonOfClass1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fieldOfClass1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Class 2 :

```
public class Class2 {

    public String receiveFieldValueOfClass1;

    Class2(){
        System.out.println("This is a valor of Jtext Field Class 1 ! = "+receiveFieldValueOfClass1);
    } 

    public static void main (String[]args){         

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, you'd like to set a variable (let's name it s) in Class2 to the value of JTextField in Class1?

Just add a public(!) method to Class2 that takes a String as argument and sets the value of s to the given String.
In Class1 just create an ActionListener for the button which calls the public method of Class2 with the value of JTextField as argument.

I could help you more if you'd include a [code sample](http://sscce.org/) in your question.

Comment: Can give me a exemple with the code bro ? I'm a new Java programer, very thanks !

Comment: what's the output of your application? I think you should learn more about object oriented programming and how the code will be executed (especially in which order). The output of the field in Class2 in its constructor won't work because you **first** create the Class2 object **and then set the field in Class2**. That means, on constructor call in Class2, its field won't be initialized yet.
You also don't have to call `toString()` on `fieldOfClass1.getText()` because it's already returning a String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()

Comment: Thanks to all ! 
Have a nice day my friends ! :)